# Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 rending and speed issues

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I have a VB.Net application that has a reference to Microsoft report viewer.

I installed the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 run time from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

I have added a reference to the dll installed and removed the previous dll in my project.

Now when i view reports it is very slow to render. It used to take 1 second for some reports and now it takes 30 seconds. Also the rendering is missing some text.